# Pom.xml - tar task

Tags: maven-2, tar

Is it possible to add a task to the pom.xml file that will create a tar.gz / .zip file.
for eample:

```
<tar type="tar.gz" source="resources/sql" tofile="target/sql.tar.gz"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably this need to be tagged with "Maven"

Answer (score 3):

Use the `maven-assembly-plugin`

Create a src/main/assembly/bin.xml as detailed at http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#bin

Put your resources sql files in the `includes` and give the format of `output` as tar.gz

Next, in your pom.xml put the reference to this plugin

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </phase>              
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Last, call this using

```
mvn package
```

Comment: I am getting: Unrecognised tag: 'assembly'. 
BTW, how do i set the target (dest/name.tar.gz)

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, it doesn't deserve a score of -1. So here is my +1.